# Missing features in HttpWebRequest and WebClient?

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, webclient

What features do you want to see in [System.Net.HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28VS.80%29.aspx) that are not included out of the box?

What cannot or cannot be easily achieved with those classes?

I'd like to be able to:

- Use bandwidth throttling when downloading (useful for large files).
- Upload multiple files and key-value pairs via HTTP post (A single file and a single collection of key-value pairs is easy using WebClient).

Answer (score 5):

I would like to see both of these classes updated to allow asynchronous operation via `Task` and `Task<T>`.

Some examples -

In WebClient, I would like to see methods like -

```
Task<string> WebClient.DownloadStringTask(Uri uri);
```

In HttpWebRequest, I'd like to see:

```
Task<Stream> HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStreamTask();
```

Granted, the second is usable using `TaskFactory.FromAsync`, but that's not as simple as it could be.

Comment: Interesting - why the multiple downvotes on what I see as missing features?

Answer (score 1):

**I wish that .NET had a HTTP connector that used the [WinINet subsystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385483%28VS.85%29.aspx).** (Or faked it really, really well.)

In a number of cases I "fall back" to MSXML/XMLHTTPRequest simply because the connections "work like IE" -- if the user can access it in IE, then they can access it via MSXML. The following is not always true about the .NET connector without a manual configuration. Uhg.

My experience comes from .NET35 and I am not sure what .NET4 changes.

Answer (score 0):

Download html page + css + images to a single MHT file.

I'd like to be able to download the web page with all CSS, images and scripts and save it to a single MHT file. Then I would use it as HTML body of MailMessage.